# 110VAC 1-HP 10A motor VS 50-60A SSR

Tags: motor, solid-state-relay, heatsink

I'd like to build a circuit to control a 1-HP 10A motor.  To switch it on and off I was thinking of using a SSR since I could pair it with a microcontroller.  I've never used one before but thought I'd give it a go since I was having trouble finding any mechanical relays that I could pair with an UNO or Nano and feel comfortable they could handle the current draw from the motor.  A search of Amazon reveals many SSRs in the 50 to 60A range for about $15.  The voltage available is 110VAC.  When using the SSR will I need a heatsink? I'm just a newbie so any additional comments are appreciated.

Comment: SSR usually is optothyristor. Drop voltage on thyristor approximately one volt( check the datasheet for specific value). So the heat dissipated is 10W. Heatsink is must.

Comment: @user263983     Thank you.